# How to make a battery draining circuit?

Tags: batteries

I have an air soft gun battery that needs to be completely before charging it because the charger does not have overcharge protection. Basically I have to time charging it.

I would like to make a circuit that would completely drain the battery as much as possible without damaging it before I hook up the battery to the charger.

How would I go around making such a circuit (that would not harm the battery)?

Here is the individual Battery information:

```
Ni-MH, 2/3 A, 1100mAh, 1.2V, 7 Batteries in the pack. The batteries are lined up + to -
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing what type of battery (no, airsoft battery does not explain it), we cannot help. Basically your asking forr a undervoltage protection circuit. Might as well look for over voltage protection instead, to avoid needing to time it at all.

Comment: @Passerby Updated Question info.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to take it off hold, but I did add to my answer. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: To be honest, any charger that is not a smart charger is only good to be thrown in the dumpster(Dont actually do this. Use it as a power supply instead because e waste is bad) and replaced with something like a turnigy accucell 6 or some other cheap rc hobby charger that actually has a clue when to stop charging. And get the temperature sensor accessory too for good measure.

Comment: O.K. I will look into that! Thanks for the info.

P.S. I do recycle all of my e-Waste.

Comment: With that number of cells, bitsmack is right - you risk killing the weakest cell. Discharging to 7V is a good plan although if you are doing it manually, the dropoff can be very sudden and watching a multimeter is tedious!

You can trickle charge (C/10 or 100mA) for many many hours without risk which will top up the cells fully. I agree though, fast timed chargers are a nuisance in this respect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of this battery, it would be unwise to discharge it.

If it's a multi-cell NiCd or NiMH, for example, then it is constructed of multiple batteries in series to give the required voltage.  If you discharge this type too low, than you will deplete the weakest cell first.  When this happens, it's polarity effectively changes (only this one cell, mind you), and that cell is destroyed.

If, instead, it's a lithium chemistry, they can respond violently to being taken too low and then charged again.  Lithium cells generally have integrated circuitry to prevent this from happening.

If you can find out what kind of battery it is, there could be a good solution.  But don't try to discharge it too low until you're sure it's ok!

---

Edit: OK, I see your update.  A NiMH cell is 1.2V, nominally.  With 7 cells, this is an 8.4V battery pack.  Once the voltage gets down to 1.0V per cell, then 95% of the energy has been discharged.  This [link](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharge_methods) has some good info.

One manufacturer cautions against discharging a cell below 0.85V.  However, I would only go down to 7.0V total (1.0V per cell), to make sure that the weakest cell has a little bit of cushion.

I think that the best thing to do, however, is to simply use the battery pack in your device until it starts seeming underpowered.  At this point, you've reached the standard depth-of-discharge that the battery charger is expecting...

I hope this helps!

Comment: Oops! Let me get my battery out! I didn't know that it could be so disastrous!

Comment: @elliotlabs Yeah. Neither of these cases generally happen in normal use.  But if the intention is to discharge them, then you''ve gotta be careful :)  So, what kind of battery is it? Let's see what we can figure out.

Comment: Thanks. So really to discharge it it should only go down 7V for the whole pack. Thanks!